# Recursively Traverse Object till last leaf node JavaScript

Tags: javascript, recursion, functional-programming, lucene

I am working with **Lucene Syntax (a AND b, c OR d)** as a search query and I need to translate this search query. In order to translate the Lucene Syntax to a JavaScript object, I use [Lucene Parser npm module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lucene) (https://www.npmjs.com/package/lucene).

for an AND query my translation needs to happen like this:
**Query**: Hyatt AND Westin
**Translated Lucene object**:

```
{
   "left":{
      "field":"<implicit>",
      "fieldLocation":null,
      "term":"Hyatt",
      "quoted":false,
      "regex":false,
      "termLocation":{
         "start":{
            "offset":0,
            "line":1,
            "column":1
         },
         "end":{
            "offset":6,
            "line":1,
            "column":7
         }
      },
      "similarity":null,
      "boost":null,
      "prefix":null
   },
   "operator":"AND",
   "right":{
      "field":"<implicit>",
      "fieldLocation":null,
      "term":"Westin",
      "quoted":false,
      "regex":false,
      "termLocation":{
         "start":{
            "offset":10,
            "line":1,
            "column":11
         },
         "end":{
            "offset":16,
            "line":1,
            "column":17
         }
      },
      "similarity":null,
      "boost":null,
      "prefix":null
   }
}
```

**Translated Search Query for AND**:
For an AND query, I get the below translation:

```
[
   [
     {
        "col":"*",
        "test":"Contains",
        "value":"Hyatt"
     },
     {
        "col":"*",
        "test":"Contains",
        "value":"Westin"
     }
   ]
]
```

**Translated Search Query for OR**:
For an OR query, I get the below translation:

```
[
   [
      {
         "col":"*",
         "test":"Contains",
         "value":"Hyatt"
      }
   ],
   [
      {
         "col":"*",
         "test":"Contains",
         "value":"Westin"
      }
   ]
]
```

For this translation I have written the function (readExpression) which recursively traverses through the input(Translated Lucene Object):

```
result = [];

isFieldImplicit(node: Node): boolean {
    return node.field === '<implicit>';
  }

isFreeTextSearch(searchText: string): boolean {
    // user RegExp for pattern matching of field.f1:abc pattern... i.e. alpha-num.alpha-num:any-char
    return !this.isContainingLuceneReservedCharacters(searchText);
  }

isAndOperator(expression): boolean {
    return expression && expression.operator && expression.operator === 'AND';
  }

isOrOperator(expression): boolean {
    return expression && expression.operator && expression.operator === 'OR';
  }

isQueryContainingQuotes(searchText: string): boolean {
    const matches = searchText.match(/"/g);
    const firstLastCharacterQuoteMatch = new RegExp(
      /((?<![\\])['"])((?:.(?!(?<![\\])\1))*.?)\1/
    );
    const isFirstAndLastCharacterQuote = firstLastCharacterQuoteMatch.test(
      searchText
    );

    if (!matches) {
      return false;
    }

    if (/""/.test(searchText) && isFirstAndLastCharacterQuote) {
      return true;
    }

    return isFirstAndLastCharacterQuote;
  }

isQueryEndingWithStar(searchText: string): boolean {
    return searchText.endsWith('*');
  }

doesQueryContainsStar(searchText: string): boolean {
    return searchText.indexOf('*') !== -1;
  }

getTestFromQuery(keyword: string): string {
    if (this.isQueryContainingQuotes(keyword)) {
      return WHERE_CLAUSE_TESTS.CONTAINS;
    } else if (this.isQueryEndingWithStar(keyword)) {
      return WHERE_CLAUSE_TESTS.CONTAINS_ANY;
    } else {
      return WHERE_CLAUSE_TESTS.CONTAINS_ANY;
    }
  }

generateFreeTextClause(node: Node): WhereClause[] {
    const searchText = node.quoted ? `"${node.term}"` : node.term;
    const clause = [
      {
        col: '*',
        test: this.getTestFromQuery(searchText as string),
        value: (node.term as string).replace('*', '')
      } as WhereClause
    ];
    return clause;
  }

generateFieldSearchClause(node: Node): WhereClause[] {
    const searchText = node.quoted ? `"${node.term}"` : node.term;
    const clause = [
      {
        col: node.field.split('.')[1],
        test: this.getTestFromQuery(searchText as string),
        value: (node.term as string).replace('*', '')
      } as WhereClause
    ];
    return clause;
  }

readExpression(expression): any {
    let left, right;
    if (expression && expression.field) {
      return expression;
    }

    if (this.isOrOperator(expression)) {
      left = this.readExpression(expression.left);
      right = this.readExpression(expression.right);
      if (left) {
        if (this.isFieldImplicit(left)) {
          this.results.push(this.generateFreeTextClause(left));
        } else {
          this.results.push(this.generateFieldSearchClause(left));
        }
      }
      if (right) {
        if (this.isFieldImplicit(right)) {
          this.results.push(this.generateFreeTextClause(right));
        } else {
          this.results.push(this.generateFieldSearchClause(right));
        }
      }
      console.log(this.results);
      return this.results;
    }
    if (this.isAndOperator(expression)) {
      left = this.readExpression(expression.left);
      right = this.readExpression(expression.right);
      if (left) {
        if (this.isFieldImplicit(left)) {
          this.results.push(this.generateFreeTextClause(left)[0]);
        } else {
          this.results.push(this.generateFieldSearchClause(left)[0]);
        }
      }
      if (right) {
        if (this.isFieldImplicit(right)) {
          this.results.push(this.generateFreeTextClause(right)[0]);
        } else {
          this.results.push(this.generateFieldSearchClause(right)[0]);
        }
      }
      console.log(this.results);
      return this.results;
    }
  }
```

It works fine for 1 level AND and OR but as soon as I have 2 level it fails.
**Query**: (Hyatt AND Westin) OR Orchid

I am expecting below translation:

```
[
   [
      {
         "col":"*",
         "test":"Contains",
         "value":"Hyatt"
      },
      {
         "col":"*",
         "test":"Contains",
         "value":"Westin"
      }
   ],
   [
      {
          "col":"*",
          "test":"Contains",
          "value":"Orchid"
       }
   ]
]
```

In the recursive call, the leaf node of OR is getting ignored and not injected inside the array of results. Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: I'd suggest that this contains both too much and too little. That's a large wall of code to try to read through, and it looks like almost everything in your input format is not necessary to the question. On the other hand, you show us a sample input and output where it's working, but only output for the case that isn't working. Can you create a more concise [mcve] including the failing case, but skipping most of the irrelevant fields? And shrink down your problematic code to only handle the AND/OR on particular terms? Finally, should your output really ignore the difference betwen AND and OR?

Comment: That's not to say that this is a bad question, but if you simplify, you're likely to get much more help.

Answer (score 1):

Without trying to dig deeply into your code (see my comments on the question), the core of this should involve a straightforward recursion.

Here I get your output from what I think would be the relevant input:

```js
const convert = (query) =>
  'operator' in query
    ? [convert (query .left), convert (query .right)]
    : {
        col: '*',
        test: 'Contains',
        value: query .term
      }

const query = {left: {left: {field: "<implicit>", fieldLocation: null, term: "Hyatt", quoted: false, regex: false, termLocation: {start: {offset: 2, line: 1, column: 3}, end: {offset: 8, line: 1, column: 9}}, similarity: null, boost: null, prefix: null}, operator: "AND", right: {field: "<implicit>", fieldLocation: null, term: "Westin", quoted: false, regex: false, termLocation: {start: {offset: 12, line: 1, column: 13}, end: {offset: 18, line: 1, column: 19}}, similarity: null, boost: null, prefix: null}, parenthesized: true}, operator: "OR", right: {field: "<implicit>", fieldLocation: null, term: "Orchid", quoted: false, regex: false, termLocation: {start: {offset: 23, line: 1, column: 24}, end: {offset: 29, line: 1, column: 30}}, similarity: null, boost: null, prefix: null}}

console .log (convert (query))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

Of course I hard-code `col: '*'` and `test: 'Contains'`; you'd have to fill them in appropriately.  And my test to see if we're at a branch or leaf (`'operator' in query`) is likely much too naïve.  And you probably will need other cases than what I have here (`AND`/`OR` pair and leaf node.)  In the end, you might replace every bit of this function, but it could well serve as a skeleton on which to grow the other requirements.

I still think your output format is odd.  This result won't distinguish between `'(Hyatt AND Westin) OR Orchid'`, `'(Hyatt AND Westin) AND Orchid'`, `'(Hyatt OR Westin) OR Orchid'`, and `'(Hyatt OR Westin) AND Orchid'`.